# Fridge works (or worked) but not the freezer

Tags: repair, refrigerator

I own a KitchenAid KSC24C8EYP02. Suddenly, the freezer portion stopped working. The fridge portion kept cold but not the freezer. I have found some posts with the opposite scenario, but not this one.

I suspected the control board and ordered a new one from Sears. Just put it in, only to discover that neither side working. The freezer is blowing air but not getting cold and the fridge is not cooling either.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would check your circulating fan, then thermostat probe. These are both located in the back of your freezer. You will have remove the covering to get to them. Take pics with your phone camera as you go. It will make it easier to put back together. As far as your new board not working, I know its hard to believe but, you can get a new board that is defective. Mine did the same thing and the fan would run, but not all the time. When I replaced it, it was working properly.

Comment: I have found similar problems with the circulation fan. I also have had the kids not close the freezer and some ice melted and refroze in the bottom blocking the air flow. The blocked air flow caused the same problem as a bad fan as a second possibility.+